# After changing res to 2560x1440 everything in all Adobe products in blurred

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-acrobat, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

After installing a new display which supports 2560x1440 res (was previously on 1920x1080), in all Adobe products everything in now blurred.

Using Adobe suite CS5 on Windows.

All UI, icons, menus, text, everything, including the actual work area of the document.
As if someone just applied a blur filter to entire screen.

Any ideas how to fix if possible?

I checked a few other programs:
Vivaldi and other browsers - all look fine
Thunderbird - fine
old Corel Draw 12 - blurred

Comment: You can try to turn off scaling in your adobe products (see settings/preferences ). Look for **HighDPI + Adobe** on google

Comment: Where is it located? I just checked all preferences in Illustrator and no scaling options of any kind, Preferences -> UI has exactly 3 settings: brightness, auto-collapse icon panels, open documents as ta... rest is cut off.

Comment: you can try: https://www.danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/ and/or this: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2231068

Comment: My applications don't start at all with external manifest, throw some kind of error. However, if I understand correctly, all it does it let the application be scaled by Windows. My Adobe applications are already scaled, and that is what creates a problem, as this scaling sucks and just blurs everything. Turning off high DPI scaling in exe properties gets you the "interface for ants" problem. So is there no way to get proper scaling in Adobe products older than CS6?